# Clickable text link in Alert Dialog to open Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want one word of the text in my Alert Dialog to be clickable and open an activity on click.

I tried to use a ClickableSpan in a SpannableString, but the click is not recognized at all...

```
public class TestDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String text = "This is a test message.";

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);

        ClickableSpan cs = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                System.out.println("Test");
            }
        };

        ss.setSpan(cs, 10, 14, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(ss)
                .setTitle("Test Title")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // do something
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // do something
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it with the help of several other posts here and youtube videos.
I use a Custom Layout showing text combined with clickable spans which I then show in the Alert Dialog:

```
public class TestDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String text = "This is a test message.";

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);

        ClickableSpan cs = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                Intent testIntent = new Intent(getContext(), Test.class);
                getContext().startActivity(testIntent);
            }
        };

        ss.setSpan(cs, 10, 14, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_view, null);

        TextView message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        message.setText(ss);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Test Title")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // do something
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // do something
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I hope I could also help you.

Answer (score -1):

First, Make your text HTML links clickable by using `Html.fromHtml`:

```
.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text))
```

and, Add this line to your Activity in Manifest:

```
<data android:host="my.app" android:scheme="http"></data>
```

Then, http://my.app should launch your activity.

Comment: I tried it but it is just shown as plain text. I also can't click on it. Isn't there a way to do it with ClickableSpans?